# Cannot pause CSS animation in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, css, animation, safari

I try to pause a CSS animation with JavaScript.
This works in all tested browsers but not in Safari on iOS, where the animation continues until the end.
How to fix or workaround this bug?

```js
(function () {
  function setAnimationPlayState (state) {
    document.getElementById ('debug').innerHTML += state + '/';
    document.getElementById ('animation').style.animationPlayState = state;
    document.getElementById ('animation').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = state;
  }
  window.addEventListener ('load', function () {
    setAnimationPlayState ('running');
    setTimeout (function () {
      setAnimationPlayState ('paused');
    }, 1000);
  });
} ());
```

```css
#animation {
  animation: test linear 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@keyframes test {
  to {
    /* 3D never pause */
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    /* 2D may pause or not */
    /* transform: translateX(100vw); */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="debug" style="color: red;">/</div>
    <div id="animation">Hello<br>this text<br>should not<br>disappear<br>completely</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My animation is 3D so I also tested with a 2D animation just in case, and the behavior is even weirder. Sometimes it works, then I reload the page and it doesn't work. This thing is driving me crazy, your help is most welcome.